# jsf2 primefaces.js error $browser.msie is null or not an object

Tags: primefaces

I have a primafaces selectOneMenu. When i click on the rendered menu the dropdown list is not coming up and the browser is giving this error. I am using IE 8 and primefaces 5. However when I change to h:selectOneMenu the drop down works fine. Please help , I am stuck. Here's my code:

```
     <p:selectOneMenu id="app" value="#{refbean.selapp}" rendered="#{refbean.selItem =='SMS NOTIFICATION'}">
              <f:selectItem itemValue="Select" itemLabel="Select Application"></f:selectItem>
              <f:selectItems value="#{refbean.appList}"></f:selectItems>
              <f:ajax event="change"
                      execute="@this"
                      render="shownotif"
                      listener="#{refbean.setNotificationValues}">
               </f:ajax>
            </p:selectOneMenu>

I also tried using  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script> but the issue still remains.



I am not able to test the ajax call because the drop down menu is not populated at all in the first place. When I click on the drop down menu i see the javascript error in the browser : `$browser.msie is null or not an object.`  Here is my full code : 



 <p:panelGrid id="showOption">
         <p:row id="showsms" rendered="#{refbean.selItem =='SMS NOTIFICATION'}">
         <p:column>
        <p:outputLabel value="#{msg['createcr.app']}" rendered="#{refbean.selItem =='SMS NOTIFICATION'}" styleClass="LabelDescription"></p:outputLabel>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="app" value="#{refbean.selapp}" rendered="#{refbean.selItem =='SMS NOTIFICATION'}">
          <f:selectItem itemValue="Select" itemLabel="Select Application"></f:selectItem>
          <f:selectItems value="#{refbean.appList}"></f:selectItems>
          <f:ajax event="change"
                  execute="@this"
                  render="shownotif"
                  listener="#{refbean.setNotificationValues}">
           </f:ajax>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        </p:column>
        </p:row>

        <p:row id="shownotif" rendered="#{refbean.selItem == 'SMS NOTIFICATION'}">
        <p:column>
          <p:outputLabel value="#{msg['createcr.notif']}" styleClass="LabelDescription"></p:outputLabel>
          </p:column>
          <p:column>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="notif" value="#{refbean.selnot}" rendered="#{refbean.selItem == 'SMS NOTIFICATION'}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="Select" itemLabel="Select Notification List"></f:selectItem>
            <f:selectItems value="#{refbean.noList}"></f:selectItems>
            <f:ajax event="change"
                    execute="@this"
                    render="showtext"
                    listener="#{refbean.setSelNotification}"></f:ajax>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
      </p:column>
        </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Tried using <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script> but issue remains

Comment: Don't include jquery yourself, PF will do it. Do other PF components work? Do you have a h:head? Do you have a form inside another form? I believe you should use p:ajax instead of f:ajax on PF components

Comment: The drop down list itself is not coming up in the first place. The browser is throwing the error $browser.msie is null or not an object. Please help , I am stuck with it for two days.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [jquery-browser-plugin](https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin) , place the [jquery.browser.min.js](https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin/blob/master/dist/jquery.browser.min.js) and include it in your webapp

> A jQuery plugin for browser detection. jQuery removed support for browser detection on 1.9.1 so it was abstracted into a jQuery plugin